# How exactly does the fetchAllIfNeeded differ from fetchAll in the JS SDK?

Tags: parse-platform

I never quite understood the *if needed* part of the description.

`.fetchAll()`
Fetches the given list of Parse.Object.

`.fetchAllIfNeeded()`
Fetches the given list of Parse.Object *if needed*.

What is the situation where I might use this and what exactly determines the need? I feel like it's something super elementary but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory and clear definition.

In the example in the API, I notice that the `fetchAllIfNeeded()` has:

```
// Objects were fetched and updated.
```

In the success while the `fetchAll` only has:

```
// All the objects were fetched.
```

So does the `fetchAllIfNeeded()` also save stuff too? Very confused here.

**UPDATES**

*TEST 1*

Going on some of the hints @danh left in the comments I tried the following things.

```
var todos = [];
var x = new Todo({content:'Test A'});  // Parse.Object
todos.push(x);
x.save();

// So now we have a todo saved to parse and x has an id. Async assumed.

x.set({content:'Test B'});

Parse.Object.fetchAllIfNeeded(todos);
```

So in this scenario, my client `x` is different than the server. But the `x.hasChanged()` is false since we used the `set` function and the change event is triggered. `fetchAllIfNeeded` returns no results. So it isn't that it's trying to compare this outright to what is on the server to sync and fetch.

I notice that in the request payload, running the `fetchAllIfNeeded` is sending the following interesting thing.

```
{where: {objectId: {$in: []}}, _method: "GET",…}
```

So it seems that on the clientside something determines whether an object *isNeeded*

*Test 2*

So now, based on the comments I tried manipulating the `changed` state of the object by setting with silent.

```
x.set({content:'Test C'}, {silent:true});
x.hasChanged(); // true
Parse.Object.fetchAllIfNeeded(todos);
```

Still nothing interesting. Clearly the server state ("Test A") is different than clientside ("Test C"). and I still results `[]` and the request payload is:

```
{where: {objectId: {$in: []}}, _method: "GET",…}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Figured it out by looking at the Parse source. See answer.

Comment: A guess is that the "if needed" relates to backbone object change event/attribute (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed). The unconditional fetchAll will refresh everything, triggering change events for all objects. The if needed variety does more work to only change objects whose state differs from the server state and alter their 'changed' attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It got me started on testing some things out. Turns out it isn't about the change property. It's about whether there are attributes and values or not. It mostly has to do with cases where you have nested children that are not included in a query of parents. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

After many manipulations, then taking a look at the source - I figured this out. Basically `fetchAllIfNeeded` will fetch models in an array that have no data, meaning there are no attribute properties and values.

So the use case would be you have lets say a parent object with an array of nested Parse Objects. When you fetch the parent object, the nested child objects in the array will not be included (unless you have the `include` query constraint set). Instead, the pointers are sent back to clientside and in your client, those pointers are translated into 'empty' models with no data, basically just blank Parse.Objects with ids.

Specifically, the Parse.Object has an internal Boolean property called `_hasData` which seems to be toggled true any time stuff like set, or fetch, or whatever gives that model attributes.

So, lets say you need to fetch those child objects. You can just do something like

```
var childObjects = parent.get('children'); // Array
Parse.Object.fetchAllIfNeeded(childObjects);
```

And it will search for those children who are currently only represented as empty Objects with id.

It's useful as opposed to `fetchAll` in that you might go through the children array and lazily load one at a time as needed, then at a later time need to "get the rest". `fetchAllIfNeeded` essentially just filters "the rest" and sends a whereIn query that limits fetching to those child objects that have no data.

In the Parse documentation, they have a comment in the callback response to `fetchAllIfNeeded` as:

```
// Objects were fetched and UPDATED.
```

I think they mean the clientside objects were updated. `fetchAllIfNeeded` is definitely sending GET calls so I doubt anything updates on the serverside. So this isn't some sync function. This really confused me as I instantly thought of serverside updating when they really mean:

```
// Client objects were fetched and updated.
```

Comment: This is an excellent finding.  Makes a lot of sense now that I see it.  The developer guide content at parse is very useful, very well written, but its a stark contrast with the API reference, where the descriptions are often no more than the method names repeated.

Comment: In general Parse has pretty good documentation but this one stumped me good based on how it was written up. :-) Thanks for your help!